# Use Auth0 decorator with Flask-RESTful resource

Tags: python, flask, auth0, flask-restful

I need to use Auth0 for my Flask-RESTful app. Auth0 has an [example](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/01-authorization) using the `requires_auth` decorator on a view function.

```
@app.route('/secured/ping')
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'])
@requires_auth
def securedPing():
    return "All good. You only get this message if you're authenticated"
```

With Flask-RESTful I use `add_resource` with a `Resource` class, not `app.route` with a view function. How do I apply `requires_auth` to `Version`?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
API = Api(app)
CORS = CORS(app, resources={r'/api/*': {'origins': '*'}})
API.add_resource(Version, '/api/v1')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Flask-Restful docs describe how to [specify decorators for a resource](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#resource-method-decorators).

> There is a property on the `Resource` class called `method_decorators`. You can subclass the `Resource` and add your own decorators that will be added to all method functions in resource.

```
class AuthResource(Resource):
    method_decorators = [requires_auth]

# inherit AuthResource instead of Resource to define Version
```